# Topological graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Given the universel covering space $\hat{X}$ of $X$ by $p:\hat{X}\rightarrow X$, there exists a bijection between subgroups $H<G=\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and covering spaces $\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ with $\tilde{X}$ connected. Per definition the space $Z$ is a topological graph if it is of the from: $$\coprod_{e\in E}{[0,1]}/r$$
with $r$ the equivalencerelation which identifie only endpoints of $[0,1]$. Given the universel covering space $\hat{X}$ we can make the space $X_H=\hat{X}/H$ (cycle space). I want to prove the following facts:

- $X_H$ is a topological graph
- $X_N=\coprod_{n\in N}{S^1}/s$ with $s$ the relation which only identify the $1\in S^1$ of all cykels and $N$ a cardinal number is semi-locally simply connected

I have rought speaking no idea ho wto solve this. Any idea?
Thanks